# How to declare a C struct with a pointer to array in ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I read the [official ctypes tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) and also searched SO, but I could not find a way to declare this kind of structure with ctypes. This structure is returned by one of the functions I write an Python interface for.

```
typedef struct{
    int i;
    float *b1;
    float (*w1)[];
}foo;
```

This is what I have so far:

```
class foo(Structure):
 _fields_=[("i",c_int),
  ("b1",POINTER(c_int)),
  ("w1",?????????)]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a pointer to an array stores the same memory address as a pointer to the first element in the array.  Therefore:

```
class foo(Structure):
    _fields_=[("i",c_int),
              ("b1",POINTER(c_int)),
              ("w1",POINTER(c_float))]
```

You can access the elements of the array using integer indexes.  For example: `myfoo.w1[5]`.

It would be better C coding style to declare `w1` as `float *w1`, so that you can access elements of the array using `myfoo->w1[5]` instead of having to dereference twice.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

I dereference 'w1' twice as I use it as a 2d array.